# Why concrete members of wdDialogEditFind are not found by reflection?

Tags: .net, com, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

I am working on a VSTO project and want to use **Word Dialog Boxes** in **Hidden Mode**, just like code below:

#### [Code from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/bhy5dcs0#Y100)

```
dynamic dialog = Application.Dialogs[Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFilePageSetup];
dialog.PageWidth = "3.3\"";
dialog.PageHeight = "6\"";
dialog.TopMargin = "0.71\"";
dialog.BottomMargin = "0.81\"";
dialog.LeftMargin = "0.66\"";
dialog.RightMargin = "0.66\"";
dialog.HeaderDistance = "0.28\"";
dialog.Orientation = "0";
dialog.DifferentFirstPage = "0";
dialog.FirstPage = "0";
dialog.OtherPages = "0";

// Apply these settings only to the current selection with this line of code:
dialog.ApplyPropsTo = "3";

// Apply the settings.
dialog.Execute();
```

I want to implement another diaglog `wdDialogEditFind`, but methods and properties are unknown. then use reflection to retrieve them (*late binding*). but no useful methods found.

```
Word.Dialog dlg = this.Application.Dialogs[Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogEditFind];

System.Type t = dlg.Type.GetType();
System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] memInfo = t.GetMembers();
    
string str = "";
foreach (System.Reflection.MemberInfo m in memInfo)
    str += m.Name + "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Word interop hides these members from you since it relies on **[COM RCW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx)**. Reflection cannot be used to iterate through the properties since they are not defined for the [`Dialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.dialog) base type. If you want to know what properties are available - see [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845471.aspx) for built-in dialog box arguments for `wdDialogEditFind`.

#### Built-in Dialog Box Arguments for `wdDialogEditFind` ([*from MSDN*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845471.aspx))

> Find, Replace, Direction, MatchCase, WholeWord, PatternMatch, SoundsLike, FindNext, ReplaceOne, ReplaceAll, Format, Wrap, FindAllWordForms, MatchByte, FuzzyFind, Destination, CorrectEnd, MatchKashida, MatchDiacritics, MatchAlefHamza, MatchControl

If you are insistent upon knowing the COM methods and properties - you can dig into [`IDispatch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883851/175679) and [weed your way through the COM types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347981.aspx).

Comment: tested with System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic, but no System.Reflection.MemberInfo returned

Comment: Updated answer - COM RCW does not expose underlying COM members.